# How to determine the key of the file uploaded on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a file uploaded over s3 bucket in some folder hierarchy. 
`/a/b/c/file_i_want_to_stream.csv`
Now, if this file was at root level, I know the key: file name itself.
However, I am unable to determine the key when in some folder.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not actually have *folders*. It is a flat object storage system.

The hierarchy you see is **actually part of the filename (Key) of the object**.

Therefore, object `/a/b/c/file.csv` is stored in the root with a name of `/a/b/c/file.csv`. It simply *appears* to be in a directory hierarchy called `/a/b/c/`.

There are also features of Amazon S3 that make this easier to use, such as the concept of a `CommonPrefix` that is effectively a folder. So, when listing bucket contents, you can ask for a listing of all objects with a CommonPrefix of `/a/b/c/`.

**Bottom line:** The Key (filename) includes the path.

Comment: When I provided the path from the link, the object was unavailable.
`https://abcd.amazonaws.com/abcd//01Public/02Country/Country_name/01div/-2div/Department+of+Aa+Bb%2C+Dairying+and+Fisheries/18th+Livestock+Census/Buffalo+by+breed/Data/Cleaned/18th+Livestock+Census%2CBuffalo+by+breed_cleaned.csv/03ad74e2-722a-4724-ad44-1e341ce84852`

What would you make out of this? How can I deduce the key from the path? You can understand the path from the aforementioned link.